# Preparing to load a kernel

Tags: linux, assembly, boot

Even though there are wonderfully complete boot loaders available, I've been writing one on and off in my spare time as an educational exercise.  I've run into a problem.

I am able to perform an initial boot and chain load other sectors with no problem.  If I were writing my own OS I'd be good to go. :)  Instead, I'm trying to bootstrap Linux.  The challenge I'm having is two-fold.

1. I understand that [I need to load the kernel (Linux) into memory at 0x100000](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/boot.txt).  I know that I should find the "HdrS" signature at offset 0x202 of the kernel.  I also know that the start address should be in 0x214.  However, when I jump to the address in that location it halts.  Obviously, it's pretty hard to wrap a debugger around this. :)  **Am I missing something in this chain of facts necessary to determine that correct start address of the kernel?**
2. I suspect that the answer to (1) could be something to do with needing to fill some memory area with hardware discovery information.  I've seen several passing references to this on [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) but I seem to be missing where this is and precisely which data needs to be there.  **Is the boot loader responsible for hardware discovery?  If so, what data needs to be put where?**

An additional point to take note of is that I am already in 32 bit protected mode because I'm dealing with creating an EFI boot system, so 16 bit real mode isn't really an option here, eliminating the real mode start location in the kernel.

Comment: It's trivial to _wrap a debugger around this_ ... just use a virtual machine. Hell, linux even comes with source code ;)

Comment: Are you trying to debug on bare metal?  Try inside bochs another machine simulator.  That has the advantage that pausing to single-step can be totally transparent, because the clock (and timer interrupts, etc.) stops.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes.  I seem to remember that Bochs has a debug connection interface, too, doesn't it?  I'll see if that helps, but all it would really show me is that I'm successfully jumping to the location indicated by 0x214... I suspect that I'm either getting my address from the wrong spot or #2 above is my problem.

Comment: You are not supposed to jump there since that's the start of the protected mode code. You need to jump to the real mode code, see `**** RUNNING THE KERNEL` section of the document you linked.

Comment: @Jester Hmmmm... ok... So, my boot loader is actually in protected mode, which is why I was jumping there...  I should switch back to real mode and jump to the real mode code?  Let me see if I can make that happen

Comment: Oh okay if you are already in PM, that should work, if you follow the `**** 32-bit BOOT PROTOCOL` part then.

Comment: Ah!! Eureka!  I hadn't seen (or read, obviously) that section!  That explains the zero page parameter block that I wasn't sure what to do with or how to initialize.  Thanks @Jester!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jester found my issue and answered both questions.  The solution was actually in the [file that I had linked](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/boot.txt), though I had missed the relevant section.  I'm including the relevant piece here for posterity:

> In 32-bit boot protocol, the first step in loading a Linux kernel
>   should be to setup the boot parameters (struct boot_params,
>   traditionally known as "zero page"). The memory for struct boot_params
>   should be allocated and initialized to all zero. Then the setup header
>   from offset 0x01f1 of kernel image on should be loaded into struct
>   boot_params and examined. The end of setup header can be calculated as
>   follow:
>
> 0x0202 + byte value at offset 0x0201
>
> In addition to read/modify/write the setup header of the struct
>   boot_params as that of 16-bit boot protocol, the boot loader should
>   also fill the additional fields of the struct boot_params as that
>   described in zero-page.txt.
>
> After setting up the struct boot_params, the boot loader can load the
>   32/64-bit kernel in the same way as that of 16-bit boot protocol.
>
> In 32-bit boot protocol, the kernel is started by jumping to the
>   32-bit kernel entry point, which is the start address of loaded
>   32/64-bit kernel.
>
> At entry, the CPU must be in 32-bit protected mode with paging
>   disabled; a GDT must be loaded with the descriptors for selectors
>   __BOOT_CS(0x10) and __BOOT_DS(0x18); both descriptors must be 4G flat segment; __BOOT_CS must have execute/read permission, and __BOOT_DS
>   must have read/write permission; CS must be __BOOT_CS and DS, ES, SS
>   must be __BOOT_DS; interrupt must be disabled; %esi must hold the base
>   address of the struct boot_params; %ebp, %edi and %ebx must be zero.

64 bit instructions can also be found in this same document.